# Display text vertically start from bottom to top in rdlc 2010

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I want to display text in column header of ssrs 2010 like below image.
i am able to display text vertically but it will display text top to bottom.

[image]

I am using visual studio 2010 and local report (RDLC file).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Version 2008 and earlier don't have this feature, see [this Microsoft Connect issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/473442).

For SSRS 2008-R2 you should be able to do this, from [the MSDN tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633659%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> 1. Create a new report or open an existing report.
> 2. If the Properties pane is not open, click the View tab and select the Properties check box.
> 3. Click the text box for which you want to change text orientation.
> 4. Locate the WritingMode property in the Properties pane and in the drop-down list select the text orientation to apply to the text box.
>      *Note*: When the properties in the Properties pane are organized into categories, WritingMode is in the Localization category.
> 5. In the list box, select Horizontal, Vertical, or Rotate270.

The `Rotate270` value is the option you're looking for.

Comment: I am using visual studio 2010 SP1 for designing report and in that only vertical and horizontal option available.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure about the VS2010 report designer, I've never used it before. But if the designer doesn't have the option you need, then the only option you've left is editing the RDL itself (i.e. the XML itself).

Comment: i already done change xml file then vs2010 give me error Rotate270 is not valid.

Comment: Alas, then see the first line of my answer. If you don't have `Rotate270` available then the answer to your question is that it's not possible.

Comment: Thanks! Very useful!

Just adding this for the sake of completion and helping who find something similar

I'm using Visual Studio 2005 and don't know which version of Sql Reporting Service, but I guess it's 2008 or earlier. There is still a WritingMode option with 2 options:

lr-tb (left right top bottom I guess) which is normal writing

tb-lr which is vertical writing.

I tried tb-lr and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Although Jeroen is correct in his statement in that it is not possible without the use of `Rotate 270`, if all you want to do is display a static word (like "Category"?) you can do the below method. Unfortunately, for those that want to display an `<<Expr>>` in this format, this method obviously would not work.

For those of us that do not have this feature, but still want to implement it, what I did was:

1. Create the text/textbox I wanted to use in Microsoft word and rotate it to the orientation I wanted to use in my report
2. Take a screenshot, a snip using the Snipping tool, whatever you want to get an image of the text/textbox
3. Using the toolbox, insert the snip into your report

This visually looks like it did the trick.

@Liquid Core to your comment, I am not sure how you found these options.