# Windows Presentation Foundation Print Label (Zebra Printer)

Tags: c#, wpf, methods, label

I am trying to print text to display vertical in Windows Forms Host. The label is printing with report viewer in WPF. Here is my code:

```
// boolean is based on true or false, when printing labels    
private bool _isReportViewerLoaded;

// method to display data in .rdlc
private void ReportViewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // if equal false run this code isReportViewerLoaded 
        if (!_isReportViewerLoaded)
        {
            // get the lot based on the parameter Id
            Lot lot = BottleLotRespository.GetLotById(this.Parameter);

            // settings the page settings
            PageSettings pg = new PageSettings();
                         pg.PrinterSettings
                           .DefaultPageSettings
                           .Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                         pg.Landscape = false;


            PaperSize size = new PaperSize("110.0 x 74.0", 433, 100);

            BottleLotDataSet bottleLotDataSet                   = new BottleLotDataSet();
            DataTable reportDataTable                           = bottleLotDataSet.LotDataTable;
            DataRow lotRow                                      = reportDataTable.NewRow();
            lotRow["Id"]                                        = lot.Id;
            lotRow["Number"]                                    = lot.Number.ToString();

            reportDataTable.Rows
                           .Add(lotRow);

            bottleLotDataSet.BeginInit();                       

            this._reportViewer.SetPageSettings(pg);
            this.reportDataSource.Name                          = "DataSet1";
            this.reportDataSource.Value                         = reportDataTable;

            this._reportViewer
                .LocalReport
                .DataSources
                .Add(this.reportDataSource);
            this._reportViewer
                .LocalReport
                .ReportEmbeddedResource                         = "BottleLotWPF.View.Report1.rdlc";

            bottleLotDataSet.EndInit(); 

            _reportViewer.RefreshReport();

            _isReportViewerLoaded = true;
        }
    }
```

My problem is that the Report1.rdlc is not allowing me to rotate the text and there is no settings for it. Is there away of adding a setting to it to rotate the text?

Answer (score 0):

In RDLC we have the option to print vertically it seems. 
please take look at the existing thread here and see if it helps.

[display-text-vertically-start-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816830/display-text-vertically-start-from-bottom-to-top-in-rdlc-2010)